# Laravel 5 testing routes

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, tdd, laravel-5

I want to test my named routes redirect to the URL they are supposed to. For example:

```
get('users/profile', ['uses' => 'UserController@profile', 'as' => 'users.profile']);
```

How can I assert that `users.profile` is indeed redirecting to `users/profile` and that the called method is indeed `UserController#profile()` ?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you could use the `Request` class and call the Request::is('users/profile') if you use the facade in your unit test. Otherwise, either instantiate the Request class or call the Facade directly.

Not sure this is what you're looking for, but that's my best shot.